# Pass variable to external js file via onClick in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to be able to pass a variable to a JavaScript function. with the below onClick event. Basically every time the `onClick` is triggered for these images a `var` is expected to be sent to a the JavaScript function. So if image one is clicked I want to send:

`var myvar = "sof273561";` to `gotowebpage()`

`gotowebpage()` function is in `show_details.js` file.

```
<div class="furnitureTypes">
<!--- furniture image 1 -->
<li><div class="furniture"><input type="image" src="images/furniture/1.jpg onClick="gotowebpage();"/><gt_descA>Sofas</gt_descA><gt_descB>$2050</gt_descB><gt_descC><a href="sofas_27356.pfd" target="_blank" style="color:#FF0000">Check catelog</a></gt_descC></div></li>
<!--- furniture image 2 -->
<li><div class="furniture"><input type="image" src="images/furniture/2.jpg onClick="gotowebpage();"/><gt_descA>Chairs</gt_descA><gt_descB>$420</gt_descB><gt_descC><a href="chairs_18119.pfd" target="_blank" style="color:#FF0000">Check catelog</a></gt_descC></div></li>
<!--- furniture image 3 -->
<li><div class="furniture"><input type="image" src="images/furniture/3.jpg onClick="gotowebpage();"/><gt_descA>Tables</gt_descA><gt_descB>$1300</gt_descB><gt_descC><a href="tables_15723.pfd" target="_blank" style="color:#FF0000">Check catelog</a></gt_descC></div></li>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<script src="js/show_details.js"> </script>
```

Comment: Maybe you should read about javascript functions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's slightly unclear how you have written your question. But you should just be able to pass these values into your `gotowebpage` function.

```
onClick="gotowebpage('sof27356');"
```

Then in your `show_details.js` file.

```
var gotowebpage = function(value){
    //do stuff with value
}
```